# Parsing JSON Array with DynamicForm Play framework 2.2.6

Tags: arrays, json, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have JSON array of Objects that comes from user page

```
{[1].id=10, [0].name=banana, [1].measurementSystem=g, [1].name=bacon, [0].id=2, [0].cal=23, [1].cal=23, [0].measurementSystem=g}
```

How can I get all IDs from this object array into a integer Java array?
I tried this:

```
    DynamicForm data = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
    for (String s : data.data().values()){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

But it returns the array of all values.

So how can I get those ids only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `DynamicForm` isn't working, I'd suggest trying to just parse the JSON as JSON. You can get a `JsonNode` object from the request using this code:

```
JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
```

Using this you can then process the JSON to pull out whatever data you need.

Working with JSON in Play should be documented [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJsonRequests).